# DataGrid binding Type issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, types, observablecollection

Here's my setup. I have the following BusinessObject classes

```
BaseClass
InheritClassA : BaseClass
InheritClassB : BaseClass
InheritClassC : BaseClass
```

I also have the following dictionary

```
Dictionary<classType is a String, ObservableCollection<BaseClass>>
```

I want to be able to, in my converter, base on the type of object I select, return the proper ObservableCollection so I can bind it to my datagrid, and autoGenerateColumn on so I can view all my properties on the grid.

However, when i just retrieve my collection back as BaseClass, it only shows me the columns for the base class. I think this is because the Type for the ObservableCollection is type of baseClass and not specific to InheritClassA/InheritClassB/InheritClassC

Is there a way to dynamically create a ObservableCollection's Type? So I can create ObservableCollection and assign casted values into it?

Is there a proper way to bind it to my datagrid so I can view the properties for the inherit class?

Thanks very much ,

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary that has as the value-type an `Object` and not a `BaseClass`. Then you can add the concrete `ObservableCollection<InheritClass[A,B,C]>` and the binding will work like you expect:

```
Dictionary<classType is a String, ObservableCollection<object>>
```

If you want to be more restrictive, declare it as `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable>`